# Override plugin ajax function in theme function.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to override plugin ajax function and need to customize

My plugin hook is:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_membership_register_user', 'custom_membership_register_user' );
```

I want to override this function in theme function.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the call of existing function by using `remove_action`

```
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_membership_register_user', 'custom_membership_register_user' );
remove_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_membership_register_user', 'custom_membership_register_user' );
```

This article explains a lot https://wpshout.com/practical-remove_action-remove_filter/